# Как найти географические координаты углов квадрата

Tags: javascript, математика, координаты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть ли возможность рассчитать координаты точек A и B при следующих известных данных:
C - точка лежащая в центре всего этого дела (ее координаты известны)
D - расстояние от центра до стороны квадрата
И если такая возможность, подскажите как

Comment: Такая возможность есть

Comment: @StrangerintheQ А разве есть разница?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ тогда в таком случае карта

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ну или к чему отнести Google Maps или Yandex maps

Comment: @StrangerintheQ size В сниппете в каких единицах измерения подразумевается?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ А если расстояние известно в км?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ спасибо, буду признателен, но в принципе я понял, 1 градус это приблизительно 111 км, то есть отсюда и выводить зависимость

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нарисовал квадрат со стороной 4 км вокруг точки интереса.

```
360/40075 - отношение длины экватора к кол-ву градусов в полной окружности
Math.cos(lat*Math.PI/180) - коэффициент искажения долготы относительно широты
```

Вместе это дает возможность пересчитать километры в дельты по широте и долготе от центра карты и получить квадрат, яндекс линейка - подтверждает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
ymaps.ready(function() {
    let lat = 60;
    let lon = 30.3;
    let size = 2; // km
    size = size / 40075*360;
    let merc = Math.cos(lat*Math.PI/180);
    new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [lat, lon],
        zoom: 11
    }).geoObjects.add(new ymaps.GeoObject({
        geometry: {
            type: 'Rectangle',
            coordinates: [
                [lat-size, lon-size/merc],
                [lat+size, lon+size/merc]
            ]
        }
    }))
});
```

```css
body, #map  {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну если правльно понял вопрос...

Comment: даже если так, откуда корень то взялся?